# Sum a columns value in a group by for the last hour and then sum the total of all 5 as total in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, window-functions

(mssql)
What I have below sums the usage and groups by FurnNbr with the current month. I want to modify it to sum in for the last hour and sum the total of all 5 in another column

```sql
SELECT
        FurnNbr,
        Sum(Usage) as TotalUsage
    FROM
        ChlUsage (nolock)
    WHERE
        DateTm Between
            DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0)
        and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
    GROUP BY
        FurnNbr
    ORDER BY
        By FurnNbr asc
```

Data needs to be for the last hour or now() minus a hour.

```
FurnNbr / TotalUsage / TotalUsageOfAll5
1           10                50
2           10
3           10
4           10
5           10
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Comment: I edited my post to show an example

Comment: Stop splattering [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) everywhere. And if you do use hints, don't use deprecated syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter on the last hour instead of the last month, you can just modify the `where` clause. On top of this, you can use window functions to compute thte overal sum:

```
SELECT
    FurnNbr,
    SUM(Usage) as TotalUsage,
    SUM(SUM(Usage)) OVER() TotalUsageOfAll
FROM ChlUsage
WHERE DateTm >= DATEADD(hour, -1, getDate()) AND DateTm < getDate()
GROUP BY FurnNbr
ORDER BY FurnNbr
```

If you want to show the total on the first row only:

```
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FurnNbr) = 1 
    THEN SUM(SUM(Usage)) OVER() 
END TotalUsageOfAll
```

Comment: that works, is there a way to do a single return for the TotalUsageOfAll?

Comment: GMB, where does the CASE statement go?

Comment: It replaces expression `SUM(SUM(Usage)) OVER() TotalUsageOfAll`

Comment: How would I go about just doing the current hour TotalUsageOfAll and not now minus one hour. I am looking to get the data within the current hour.

Comment: @JShaffer: you can do that with an expression similar to the one you where originally using (just use `hour` instead of `month`).